Calculate the value of $f(2)+g(2)$
Let $f(x)$ and $g(x)$ be two real polynomials of degree $2$ and $1$ respectively. If $f(g(x))=8x^2-2x$ and $g(f(x))=4x^2+6x+1$, then value of $f(2)+g(2)$ is
Now I assumed $f(x)=ax^2+bx+c$ and $g(x)=px+q$. I calculated $f(g(x))$ and $g(f(x))$ and compared it with given functions to get $f(x)=2x^2+3x+1$ and $g(x)=2x-1$ and hence calculated the answer but is there any way to find $f(2)+g(2)$ without calculating $f(x)$ and $g(x)$ separately as it is way too calculative.

Can you show / describe your calculations to see why it is "too calculative"? FWIW The "expand and compare" approach is what I would do, since it doesn't require much further thought. $\quad$ There are some simplifying tricks to use, like we can tell that $ b/a = 6/4$ and $ a = 4^2 / 8 = 2$ (but those should also fall out from your equations).

In my opinion the answers posted so far don't answer the question. It was asked how to do it without calculating $f$ and $g$. I would suggest the following stronger question: is there an expression of the form $$f+g = h(f \circ g, , g \circ f)$$ if $f$ and $g$ are of degree 2 resp. 1 and $h$ does not depend on $f$ and $g$?

"as it is way too calculative"  Everyone is entitled to their opinion but this is nowhere near too calculative. $f(g(x))=8x^2-2x$ means that $ap^2 = 8$ and $g(f(x))=4x^2 + 6x + 1$ means that $ap=4$ and that makes it immediate that $p=2$ and $a=2$ and ... everything else falls into place immediately.

Preamble: This solution still essentially calculates the explicit value for $f(x)$ and $g(x)$, but without an explicit "substitute and expand and solve system of equations" which I think is what OP did (asking for details).  Instead, we make observations about these polynomials to draw almost-immediate conclusions about their values, and proceed from there.
In essence, the tedious calculations is replaced by the astute observations. (I'm not saying one is better than the other. There are times when I'd gladly brute force my way out.)
Solution:
Let's write $ f(x) = A(x - B)^2 + C$, instead of $ax^2 + bx + c$. Keep $g(x) =  px+q$.
Show that

$g(x)$ cannot be a constant.
Range of $g(x) $ is all real numbers. Hence range of $f(x)$ = range of $f(g(x))  = [-1/8, \infty)$, so $ C = - 1/8$.
The x-coordinate of the turning point of $f(x)$ is the same as the x-coordinate of the turning point of $g(f(x))$. Hence  $B = - \frac{6}{4} $.
The leading coefficient of $f(g(x))$ is $Ap^2 = 8$. The leading coefficient of $g(f(x))$ is $Ap = 4$. Hence $ p = 2, A = 2$.
So $f(x) = 2(x + \frac{3}{4} ) ^2 - \frac{1}{8}  = 2x^2 + 3x + 1$.
From $g(f(x)) = 2f(x) + 1$, we get $q = -1$. So $g(x) = 2x - 1$.


The affine map $g:\Bbb R\to\Bbb R$ is non-constant hence bijective. Let $h:=g^{-1}$. From $f(y)=8(h(y))^2-2h(y)$ and $f(x)=h(4x^2+6x+1)$, we derive:
$$8\left(h(t)-\frac18\right)^2-\frac18=h\left(4\left(t+\frac34\right)^2-\frac54\right).$$

The minimum value of the LHS is $-\frac18$, attained when $h(t)=\frac18$.
The extremum value of the RHS is $h\left(-\frac54\right)$, attained when $t=-\frac34$.
Therefore,
$$h\left(-\frac54\right)=-\frac18\quad\text{and}\quad h\left(-\frac34\right)=\frac18$$
or equivalently
$$g\left(-\frac18\right)=-\frac54\quad\text{and}\quad g\left(\frac18\right)=-\frac34$$
hence $g(x)=2x-1$, $f(2)=h(29)=\frac{29+1}2=15$, and
$$f(2)+g(2)=15+3=18.$$


Oh wow, I love this approach! That's a clever way to drive the first equation.

If you just consider the leading terms of each polynomial, then:
$$f(g(x)) \to a(px)^2 = ap^2x^2$$
$$g(f(x)) \to p(ax^2) = apx^2$$
Matching up the $x^2$ coefficients with the given polynomials gives $ap^2 = 8$ and $ap = 4$.  Clearly (dividing the two equations), $p = 2$, and thus $a = 2$.
Next, consider the equation $g(f(x)) = 0 \implies 4x^2+6x+1 \implies x = \frac{-3 \pm 2\sqrt{5}}{4}$.  Since $g$ has only one root, in order for both $x$ values to satisfy the equation, they must have the same $f(x)$ value, i.e.,
$$f\left(\frac{-3 + 2\sqrt{5}}{4}\right) = f\left(\frac{-3 - 2\sqrt{5}}{4}\right)$$
Which implies that $f$ is symmetric about $x = -\frac{3}{4}$.  Recall that a parabola $y = ax^2 + bx + c$ is symmetric about $x = -\frac{b}{2a}$, so $-\frac{b}{2a} = -\frac{3}{4} \implies b = \frac{3a}{2}$.  But we already know that $a = 2$, so $b = 3$.
Now we have only two unknown coefficients, the constant terms.
$$f(x) = 2x^2 + 3x + c$$
$$g(x) = 2x + q$$
And straightforward substitution gives:
$$f(g(x)) = 2(2x + q)^2 + 3(2x + q) + c = 8x^2 + (8q + 6)x + 2q^2 + 3q + c$$
Matching up the $x$ coefficient with the given $f(g(x))=8x^2-2x$ gives $8q + 6 = -2$, so $q = -1$, and:
$$f(g(x)) = 8x^2 - 2x + c - 1$$
And $c - 1 = 0$, so $c = 1$.
$$\boxed{f(x) = 2x^2 + 3x + 1 \\ g(x) = 2x - 1}$$
And you can verify that $g(f(x)) = 2(2x^2 + 3x + 1) - 1 = 4x^2 + 6x + 1$ as given.
Yes, this answer does explicitly calculate $f$ and $g$, but I did it in such a way that there are never more than two unknown coefficients in the same equation.
Finally, $f(x) + g(x) = 2x^2 + 5x$, and you can simply plug in $x = 2$ to get:
$$\boxed{f(2) + g(2) = 18}$$
